# I get a parse error related to the master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I made a master page , and Ihave this error:
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'Hogwarts_School.accmaster' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage'.

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="accmaster.master.cs" Inherits="Hogwarts_School.accmaster" %>

Comment: It is just as it says in the error message. Your class must inherit from MasterPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your accmaster.master.cs it should look something like this:

```
public class accmaster: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    // code goes here
}
```

The "System.Web.UI.MasterPage" text indicates the class that the accmaster extends.